# Parse-Server Not Downloading PFFile due to App Transport Security

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform, app-transport-security, parse-server

I'm in the process of migrating from Parse's backend to the Parse-server on Heroku and MongoDB.

I had everything working smoothly (including loading PFFiles) with this new backend change, however, I'm now getting errors after adding the `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` parameter, however, that might not be the cause.

Whenever I try to load an `PFFile` (image) I'm getting the following messages in the log:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2016-02-20 19:55:48.242 HoopMaps[35976:682425] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
2016-02-20 19:55:48.243 HoopMaps[35976:682425] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.730434 seconds.
2016-02-20 19:55:50.137 HoopMaps[35976:682402] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
2016-02-20 19:55:50.138 HoopMaps[35976:682402] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 3.460868 seconds.
2016-02-20 19:55:53.857 HoopMaps[35976:682403] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
2016-02-20 19:55:53.857 HoopMaps[35976:682403] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 3 after sleeping for 6.921736 seconds.
2016-02-20 19:56:01.162 HoopMaps[35976:682821] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
2016-02-20 19:56:01.162 HoopMaps[35976:682821] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 13.843473 seconds.
2016-02-20 19:56:15.264 HoopMaps[35976:682785] [Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
```

While I can disable ATS, this would be bad practice, and I'd much rather prefer HTTPS. In addition, the error code is "100" but I can connect to my server and retrieve objects and user data.

How can I load PFFiles using Parse-server while retaining the HTTPS?

Answer (score 3):

The best idea would be to get a SSL certificate for your API but if that's not possible a momentary workaround would be to add your domain as an exception for ATS.

This way, you won't need to disallow ATS completely (which is a bad practice as you pointed out), but your app will still allow insecure calls from your domain.

To do this open your Info.plist file and add `App Transport Security Settings`. Then select `Exception Domains` and add your domain to the list.

[image: App Transport Security Settings]

[image: Exception Domains]

This is how your `Info.plist` should look at the end:

[image: Your domain]

Answer (score 0):

Apple announced at WWDC 2016, that it will no longer accept Apps with App Transport Security Setting work-arounds, starting 2017.